# Node package installation failing because Node's looking in my root directory for dependacies

Tags: node.js, filesystems, npm, node-modules

While using `npm` to install packages I've recently had an issue where errors pop up that `Node` can't find modules/scripts. For some reason it's looking in my `C:/` directory, and not `C:/my-project/node_modules`. This library in particular has been troublesome, but I have seen this happen before too.

I'm running Win7 x32 with v0.10.35 of `Node`.

This is an example of what I see when I try to install `node-sass`:

```
C:\node\test>npm install node-sass
> node-sass@2.0.0-beta install C:\node\test\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js


module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\scripts\install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3

npm ERR! node-sass@2.0.0-beta install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@2.0.0-beta install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "node-sass"
npm ERR! cwd C:\node\test
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

A coworker sent me his `install.js` file, and I placed it in my root just to see what happens. Unfortunately the installation still fails once `npm` tries to install modules that the root module requires.

Comment: Do you have an `.npmrc` file? If so, please provide it :)

Comment: @AlexFord I haven't heard of `.npmrc` files before and just started looking in too them. Thanks for the tip! Which one would be most valuable?

Comment: If you don't have one then it's not relevant. It's just the configuration file for NPM. I'm not that familiar with node on Windows anymore though :/

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem while trying to install node-sass onto my Windows system. I reported this as a node-sass issue (see [Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit: gulp-sass install failing due to node-sass@2.1.1 install script failure](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1012)).

I added some additional logging to my local install of node to see what is actually going on and discovered the following:

nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js is used to start scripts\install.js
By adding some additional logging, I discovered that spawn.js is using the following command line to start install.js: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c node scripts/install.js`

In a separate command prompt window, I changed to my c:\test directory and I ran `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c node` to see which directory node is using.

At the node > prompt, I ran `process.cwd()`. This displayed: `c:\\` and not `c:\\test`

When I saw `c:\\` above, I remembered that I added an Autorun setting to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` in my Windows registry to automatically run a start up script every time cmd.exe is started. And when I looked at my start up script, I noticed that the last command in that script is: `cd c:\`. This causes every instance of cmd.exe to use c:\ as its starting directory.

After removing `cd c:\` from my start up script, npm install node-sass ran correctly.

I hope this is helpful to others who have run into the issue described in the question above.

Comment: Going to try this out! Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your 'prefix' configuration variable is set.  You can find out by running

```
> npm c get prefix
```

It should be set to something reasonable for global packages; if it is set to "C:\" then that may be causing your problem.

You can find out where `npm` is looking for configuration by running

```
> npm c get globalconfig
> npm c get localconfig
```

And you can list all the configuration variables

```
> npm c ls -l
```

Comment: Hmm I just tried this. It looks like my prefix is correct, because it's returning `C:\Users\jamesm\AppData\Roaming\npm`.

Comment: Try looking through the output of `npm c ls -l` then to see if something is unreasonably set to `C:\`.  

Another possibility - although it's unlikely if you didn't create it yourself, there may be a per-project `.npmrc` somewhere, messing things up.